# Unified access to files from native code

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-activity

My application has two sources of data: standard assets folder and downloaded file. Now I access assets (from C++ code) using `AAssetManager_open`, `AAsset_read` etc. And I read data from downloaded file using good old `fopen`, `fread` etc. Is it possible to access all the data in unified way using `fopen`, `fread` stuff? In other words, can I change

```
AAssetManager* assetManager = g_state->activity->assetManager;
AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(assetManager, filename, AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
int ret = AAsset_read(asset, buf, size);
```

to

```
char *filenameFull = SomehowGetFullPathToAssetsFile(filename);
FILE *fp = fopen(filenameFull, "rb");
int ret = fread(buf, size, 1, fp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, you can't access them in an unified way because because assets lay in your APK file and not on ordinary file system. One workaround might be to extracting your resources to file system in a setup/initialization phase then use them from there afterwards.